# Can JSLint be built as a C++ library

Tags: javascript, api, validation, jslint

I require JavaScript validation in a script editor I am writing in C++.

I am aware that JSLint provides sources, is it possible to build JSLint as a C++ library that I can then use with their API without requiring the use of their exe.

If not, is there any other similar open source C++ libraries to validate JavaScript and provide error details?

Thanks.

Ref:
http://www.javascriptlint.com/docs/running_from_your_windows_program.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the same approach I used for [jslint4java](http://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/): embed a JavaScript interpreter along with a copy of JSLint.